# Directed Graph vertices and edges reversed

Tags: performance, algorithm, graph, directed-graph

So I'm working on this problem:

[image]

Here's what I have so far

```
a) Create a new graph with the same size 2-dimensional array, B. Iterate 
through the original graph's 2-dimensional array, A, which is of size VxV, 
where V is the number of vertices in the graph. If A[i][j] is true, then an 
edge exists there. Set B[j][i] true in the new reversed graph's matrix. 
The algorithm will be of complexity V^2 since it needs to iterate through 
all of the 2-dimensional array.

b) Create a new graph with an empty array, B, of size V, where V is the 
number of vertices. Iterate through the array of lists in the original 
graph, A. if there is a list  at A[i] then iterate through each one and i to
the corresponding B[x] where x is the integer in the list. The algorithm 
will be complexity of V + E since it needs to iterate through an array of 
size V, and then a total list elements of size E.
```

Firstly, I would like some double checking on my answer. I'm not that familiar with directed graphs and am not particularly skilled at finding the efficiency/complexity of algorithms. I think I did it correctly but I would like some help if I need it. I also am looking for any ideas to make it more efficient. These were the first algorithms to pop into my head so I feel like there's probably a better way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your a) is correct. In matrix language, you are finding the *transpose* of the matrix A. One small detail to think about is whether you need to set the non-edge entries of B equal to false. That depends on the language, though most languages (I think) would set all entries of B to false or 0 when the memory is initialized. The complexity is indeed `O(V^2)`.

Your b) is not worded well. But I think you have the idea. You have to push something into the list at B[x]. Describe x better. The complexity is indeed `O(V+E)`.

There's not much you can do to make them more efficient. You have to process every pair of vertices in the first case, and every edge in the second. In the case of adjacency matrix, you could swap the order of the vertices before you look up, so if you are asked whether there's an edge going from (x,y), you return the answer for (y,x) instead, but if you do that more than `V^2` times you don't come out ahead. Same with adjacency lists.